# C# System.InvalidOperationException: The current TransactionScope is already complete

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, invalidoperationexception

I have encounter this error while executing my source code. But it seems not much information I could get on the internet. Thus, I am hoping may get some clue from the professionals here.

Source Code

```
public List<string> GetData (List<long> Id)
{
    List<string> data;
    string sql = "select * from tblSample with(nolock) where SampleId in @sampleId";
    Dapper.DynamicParameters param = new Dapper.DynamicParameters();
    param.Add("@sampleId", Id);

    try
    {
        data = this.queryrunner.QueryList(sql, param);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
    }

    return data;
}
```

QueryRunner class method

```
    private void OpenConnection()
    {
        if (this.conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            this.conn.Open();
        }
    }

    public List<t> QueryList(String sql, DynamicParameters param)
    {
        List<t> t;

        try
        {
            OpenConnection();
            t = this.conn.Query<t>(sql, param).ToList();
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            logger.Debug(ex.Message, ex);
            LogSqlErrorException(this.conn.Database, sql, param);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection();
        }

        return t;
    }
```

Here is part of the error log:-

> System.InvalidOperationException: The current TransactionScope is already complete.
>   at System.Transactions.Transaction.get_Current()
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetFromTransactedPool(Transaction& transaction)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

Comment: post some code dude!

Comment: most likely you're trying to use transaction after it was closed, but without piece of related code House MD would fail to diagnose exception

Comment: I have updated my post with the source code.

Comment: at which line is the exception happening

Comment: Exception trow when calling `this.queryrunner.QueryList(sql, param);` > `OpenConnection();` > `this.conn.Open();`

Comment: You should open a new connection and dispose it for each QueryList query. Let connection pooling do the heavy lifting of reuse.

Comment: Yes, use connection pooling. This check is not correct: if (this.conn.State != ConnectionState.Open). What if the State is Broken or Connecting or...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `OpenConnection` is a bit of a smell, I'm guessing this is where your problem is

```
try
{
    OpenConnection();
    ...
```

It would make more sense

```
try
{
    //OpenConnection();
    conn.Open();
    queryrunner.QueryList(sql, param)
}
finally
{
    //CloseConnection();
    conn.Close();
}
```

This way you are forcing yourself to control the connection life cycle and not trying to be tricky and second guess it within another context

> Its actually better if you put it a `using` statement, however i'm not
> sure of the framework you are using, and/or the syntax